# show hide div using jquery icheck plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I work With [iCheck Jquery Plugin](http://fronteed.com/iCheck) For Beautify select/check box. Now I need to `show/hide` `div` after checked box using `jquery` But this not work with icheck plugin.

HTML:

```
<input tabindex="5" type="checkbox" id="minimal-checkbox-1">test
<div class="max_tickets">
    <input type="text" name="opwp_wootickets[tickets][0][maxtickets]" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('input').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal',
    radioClass: 'iradio_minimal',
    increaseArea: '20%'
});

$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    $(this).next('.max_tickets').toggle(this.checked);
}).change();
```

How do ca I fix this?

`NOTE: if disable icheck plugin, jquery show/hide worked But after enabled icheck jquery not work.`

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Gtd5w/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the [`ifChanged`](http://fronteed.com/iCheck/#usage) :

> input's checked, disabled or indeterminate state is changed

The event is fired by the plugin, consider that the plugin changes the DOM by adding its element so your starting HTML structure is a bit changed.

After the plugin call your element will not have a sibling called `.max_tickets`, but it's a sibling of its parent.

Code:

```
$('input').on('ifChanged', function () {
    $(this).parent().next('.max_tickets').toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/p5UgK/

Comment: Just to add, this code should be added only after calling iCheck() method on the input element else it won't work in the opposite order.

Comment: In case of radio buttons:  'ifChecked' should be passed instead of 'ifChanged' else you will have the function called twice: once for the radio getting checked and again for the radio getting unchecked. However for the current scenario ifChanged works best.

Answer (score 0):

I have just check the link link you gave for iCheck plugin. How it interacts with the checkbox is it wrap checkbox with div and adds other items and some styling therefore your `$(this).next('.max_tickets')` selector would not work as it as new parent now.

plugin converts this

```
<li>
   <input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" id="input-1">
   <label for="input-1">Checkbox, <span>#input-1</span></label>
</li>
```

to this

```
<li>
    <div class="icheckbox_square-blue" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false"><input tabindex="1" type="checkbox" id="input-1" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"><ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"></ins></div>
    <label for="input-1" class="">Checkbox, <span>#input-1</span></label>
</li>
```

so what you need do is find a new way of selecting to `div.max_tickect` I suggest wrap your code with a div has class and find your div from this parent. Please check above code;

```
   <div class="check_container">
       <input tabindex="5" type="checkbox" id="minimal-checkbox-1">test
       <div class="max_tickets">
           <input type="text" name="opwp_wootickets[tickets][0][maxtickets]" />
       </div>
    </div>


$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    $(this).parent("div.check_container").find('.max_tickets').toggle(this.checked);
}).change();
```

should work for you.

also apparently iCheck overrides the default events. please try to use following binder.

```
$('input').on('ifChecked', function(event){
  alert(event.type + ' callback');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define callbacks in the ICheck plugin.

```
$('input').on('ifChanged', function(event){
     $('.max_tickets').toggle(this.checked);
});
```